# Better way to do a customized layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout, margin

I decided to edit the question, because I realized that is unclear and wouldn't solve my problem. Then I will make a different question.

To my project I need of a layout customized by the own user, so the user can move, resize, add or remove each box.

Look the [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/PhelipeRocha/qbpr52h5/):

if I just add some margin in the `.square` or a padding in the `main` it desconfigure the layout. How can I do it, and continue without desconfigure the layout.

**JS:**

```
$main_h = $("main").height();
$main_w = $("main").width();
$margin = parseFloat($("main").css("margin-right"));

$(".square").each(function(x) {

    $(eval("square"+x)).height(parseFloat(($main_h*$(this).attr("data-height"))-($margin*3)));

    $(eval("square"+x)).width(parseFloat(($main_w*$(this).attr("data-width"))-($margin*3)));

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<main>
    <section id="square0" class="square" data-width="0.2" data-height="0.5"></section>
    <section id="square1" class="square" data-width="0.2" data-height="0.5"></section>
    <section id="square2" class="square" data-width="0.2" data-height="0.5"></section>
    <section id="square3" class="square" data-width="0.2" data-height="0.5"></section>
    <section id="square4" class="square" data-width="0.2" data-height="0.5"></section>
    <section id="square5" class="square" data-width="0.2" data-height="0.5"></section>
    <section id="square6" class="square" data-width="0.8" data-height="0.5"></section>
</main>
```

I use `data-width` and `data-height` cause I intend that use salve this information, to after can load and then get the same layout again.

I hope I have been clearer now, and thanks for the suport!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: <table> seems to be a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you mean but that layout can be achieved by css alone, this even works starting from ie7 (or even 6)

```
main {
    background: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0.5% 0 0 0.5%;
}

.square {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 32.833%;
    height: 32.833%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0 0.5% 0.5% 0;
}

.square:hover {
    border: 3px solid rgba(153,217,234,.5);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbpr52h5/1/